# how to make cerbot installed ssl work correctly?

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean, certbot

i did setup my website on digital ocean i did use `ubuntu 20.04` vm the website is basic mern application and i did use `nginx 1.18.0` as a reverse proxy and the intital nginx configuration was like that

```
server {
    listen 80
    server_name kwarezma.one www.kwarezma.one;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }
    location /api {
    # This is my nodejs API
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }




}
```

the path to my conf is `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`
after using certbot to install ssl my config changed to this

```
server {
    server_name kwarezma.one www.kwarezma.one;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }
    location /api {
    # This is my nodejs API
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/kwarezma.one/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/kwarezma.one/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}


server {
    if ($host = www.kwarezma.one) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = kwarezma.one) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name kwarezma.one www.kwarezma.one;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

but now when i visited my website kwarezma.one or [www.kwarezma.com](http://www.kwarezma.com) it docent work and i have no clue what happened so any help here will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

1-  read my answer  here :
[cannot install certbot on amazon linux2 nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68310522/cannot-install-certbot-on-amazon-linux2-nginx/69234550#69234550)

2- be sure  that  you  have a  A record ( for your  domain ) or  a CNAME record ( for your  subdomain ) well configured.

3- Next check your  issue  from this  step  by recreating a ssl certificate for your  domain or subdomain  :

```
 sudo certbot --nginx
```

( some  where in  output,  certbot will ask you  the
domain name or  the  subdomain for  which  you  want  to  install ssl )